# How to control the number of messages processing simultaneously in a single worker/consumer machine in amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Below are the configuration of my SQS and description of my use case

1. I am pushing ~1000 messages per minute to AWS SQS and worker machine needs ~30 seconds to process a single message and uses significant amount of RAM to process that message.
2. worker machine poll the SQS for every 10 Seconds and each time it may get 10 messages.
3. Since for every 10 seconds a dameon in the worker, polls the SQS, so large number of messages are end up getting parallely processed and throwing memory errors.
4. SQS Queue type is, Standard.

My question how to control the number of parallel messages processed by the consumer, like at any given time only 3 message should be processed parallely?

Also even if i increase the number of consumers, some consumer may end up processing a lot of messages right? because of the worker polling SQS for every 5 seconds.

I am new to this AWS SQS, kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: though unrelated to your question, how are you managing to send 1000 messages to the queue per second? I am unable even to do this as a test. tried in java but aws has a 50 connection limit hence 50 threads which takes around 12 mins to send 5000 messages ie. around 400 msgs per second.